# how to extract list of file names and created date of file with Dos (command prompt)

Tags: cmd

In Windows command prompt, I'm trying to list only path, file name and created date, of all files including in a folder and its sub folders. Like:

```
E:\>dir /s /b>LIST_FILES.TXT
```

Problem is that I don't know how to show created date of file. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dir /T:C filename` or `dir /T:C` if you want it recursive.