# How to get list of file names and created date of each file in excel file (separately each one in one column)

Tags: windows, cmd

with reference to my  [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51121662/how-to-extract-list-of-file-names-and-created-date-of-file-with-dos-command-pro) 
In Windows command prompt, I'm trying to list only path, file name and created date, of all files including in a folder and its sub folders. Like:

```
dir /s /b>list_of_files.txt
```

i like to get list of file names and created date of each file in excel file (separately each one in one column) but i do not know how?

Comment: Do you know what the creation date of a file is? It is the date/time on which a file was created in __this__ directory. It is not the date/time on which the file was created first time at all. So if a file is copied from directory A to directory B, the file has a new creation date in directory B while the last modification date is not changed which means the creation date is newer than the last modification date. So is the creation date really the file date you want?

Comment: I suggest to open a command prompt window, run `dir /?` and read the output help. The option `/B` is for bare format which means only file name + file extension, on additionally using `/S` also with file path. You want more than just full qualified file name, so you need to run `dir /A-D /T:C /S` filtered with __FOR__ or __FINDSTR__. Run in cmd prompt window `for /?` and `findstr /?` for help on those two commands.

Comment: In case of you really want the creation date of a file in its current directory instead of last modification date written into a CSV file separated by comma or whatever is the delimiter according to your region and language settings, you have to edit the question and add an example output of `dir /A-D /T:C /S`. The output of __DIR__ without option `/B` is language dependent and so can be filtered only correct if we know what your machine outputs on running this command line. Creation of a CSV file with `"file path","file name",last modification date` would be much easier using just __FOR__.

Comment: By the way: A [CSV file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) is __not__ an Excel file. Microsoft Excel is just one of many, many applications which can read a comma-separated values file. The installer of Microsoft Excel just registers the file extension `.csv` for being opened with Excel. But you or any other application/installer can change this registration. Real Microsoft Excel files have the file extension `.xls` or `.xlsx`. Windows command processor is not capable creating binary encoded Excel files, just text encoded CSV files.

Comment: thanks @mofi , your comment were very helpful for me and solved my problem

Comment: Switch from cmd to PowerShell v5 or newer, [Instal Module ImportExcel](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel) and run this in the shell/or a script file `dir -r -file|select fullname,creationtime|export-excel test.xlsx -show` and excel opens with the content you desire. https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BoQJ.png

Answer (score 0):

Excel, and many other applications, will read a CSV file. In a recent version of Excel, use `Data > From Text` to open the .csv file.

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse |
    Select-Object -Property FullName,LastWriteTime |
    Export-Csv -Path .\t.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

If you must run this from a cmd.exe shell, put the code above into mkdircsv.ps1. Then use the following command.

```
powershell -NoProfile -File .\mkdircsv.ps1
```